# linux kernel dump - at what time did that happen?

Tags: linux-kernel, coredump

I have a kernel dump file.

Supposing the file creation time is not reliable, can I find out the time of the panic by using crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Things that make the file creation time unreliable might also make the date/time information inside the dump unreliable... or are you saying something changed the file metadata afterward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the [crash tool](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/08/15/a-quick-overview-of-linux-kernel-crash-dump-analysis/) for analysis. The field DATE might be what you are looking for. [This tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html) is also very good.

Also, checking the system's logs might reveal some information about the time of the crash.

Comment: crash is what I'm using. DATE is it, I just was blind. Thanks

Comment: on the other hand, DATE says it was 21:24:45, but syslog happily continues through that point with no issues... DATE is suppoed to be the time of the crash, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what DATE means. Be sure the *day* information also matches before jumping to any conclusion.

Comment: it does. Seems like reboot happened around 22:25, which is a lot later.